# Is it possible to login to a Linux guest VM from the ESXi console?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-esxi

Is it possible to login to a linux guest from the ESXi console - *not* via tcp stack, like zlogin in solaris global zone to a non-global zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe so.

VMware always gives guests a graphical console, and I've never seen a menu option for it.

XEN just added VGA passthrough to XEN 4.0, and you could always do this with linux guests using the text console.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm sure it's possible to do this with just the ESXi console, you probably shouldn't because it's easy enough to redirect [virtual serial ports](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50/GUID-A779C84D-4324-4D32-AF43-BBD962ABC9E3.html) between two VMs. Just have VMWare add a named pipe serial port to your virtual machine and then configure Linux to use it as a serial console.  You then plumb that serial port to another serial port in the second VM running Windows + HyperTerminal (or Linux + minicom, etc) and you're done.

If you were looking to deploy this across a fleet of virtual machines or have it survive a vMotion event, you'd need to setup a Virtual Serial Port Concentrator (vSPC) which acts a proxy between your VM and the serial client.  There are a handful of commercial products or you could try the open source [vSPC.py](http://sourceforge.net/p/vspcpy/).